# How to use one external predicted variable in a LSTM model for multi step time series

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, python, keras

I am trying to predict energy consumption hour-by-hour with two past years of data for training and one year for testing. The training dataset contains the amount of energy consumed in a given hour and a given day as well as the predicted temperature for that hour(this predicted temperature for the given hour was obtained one week before that hour it was taken by experts in this field). I have learnt how to build a LSTM model with keras in order to use just the previous energy consumption in order to predict the future one, as well as how to use the temperature data of the previous days in order to predict the future energy consumption, but I don't find anywhere how could I make use of the energy consumption and temperature data from the past observations, as well as the predicted temperature data for the future observation that I want to predict. That is, how could I get a model working where I feed it with each predicted temperature for a concrete hour and its energy consumption and for predicting I make use of all the past energy consumptions, predicted temperatures and the predicted temperature for the hour I want to predict?  Any reference papers or suggestions?
Sorry for not attaching my code, but there are quite a lot lines of codes and I think the idea is clear.